# Remove an item from associative array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of objects, example

```
Item[0] ="{ id1: 1}";
Item[1] ="{ id2: 2}"; 
Item[2] ="{ id3: 3}";
```

I have to delete an item by knowing an specific id. For example, if i get id2, i have to delete Item[1].

I tried to solve it, but it deletes the last item

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var _item = items[i];
            var funcId = getValueKey(_item);

        if(funcId == _item)
        {
            delete items[i];
        }      
        };
```

The getValueKey func

```
getValueKey: function(obj){
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                return key;

            }
        }
```

Comment: This is an array of strings, not an array of objects.

Comment: What weird formatting is this? Why are you using strings? What makes your code "associative" when you don't refer to the ID in the array key?

Comment: You don't have array of objects. You have array of strings.

Comment: And if the strings weren't there, objects are `key:val` not `key=val`

Comment: Iterate over the members of the array until you find the one you want to remove, then use [splice](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12).

Comment: If you don't care about IE[6..8], you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a nice callback

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky There are shims anyway for ES5 features. Stop caring about old browsers ;)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, it's array of objects, i edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, thanks to me..

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var _item = items[i];
            var funcId = getValueKey(_item);
            if(funcId ==id) {
                delete items[i];
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer may work, but it seems like much more code than is required.

```
function removeMemberByValue(arr, value) {

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (arr[i] && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(value));

      //Do 1 of the following, not both:

      // to remove member i (i.e. there will no longer be a member i)
      delete(arr[i]);

      // Remove member i and shift later members -1
      arr.splice(i, 1);

      return arr;  // return is optional
  }
}
```

In the above, the first option will result in removal of the member but all other members will keep the same index, e.g.

```
var arr = [{id1: 1}, {id2: 2}, {id3: 3}];
removeMemberByValue(arr, value); // [not defined, {id2: 2}, {id3: 3}]
```

where *not defined* means "does not exist".

The second option will move later members 1 lower in index, so:

```
removeMemberByValue(arr, value); // [{id2: 2}, {id3: 3}]
```

Choose whichever suits.